# What does return value -1, 0, 1 means exactly in Java collection sort with Comparator interface compare method?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, collections, comparator

**What I understand**
If the return value is 0, then there is nothing to do. If it is -1, then the two values will be swept. If we want to change the order (asc/desc), just change the comparison operators.
**What I found on the websites**
The return value will be -1, 0 or 1 as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
**What I want to know**
Why do we need the return value 1? I tested my program without return value 1 and it sort correctly.

The following program sort students objects by grade with ascending order. If the sorting order is wanted to change, change the comparison operator.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student("JJJ", 5);
    Student s2 = new Student("DDD", 2);
    Student s3 = new Student("RRR", 4);
    Student s4 = new Student("CCC", 4);
    Student s5 = new Student("GGG", 3);
    Student s6 = new Student("JJJ", 1);
    List < Student > ls = new ArrayList < > ();
    ls.add(s1);
    ls.add(s2);
    ls.add(s3);
    ls.add(s4);
    ls.add(s5);
    ls.add(s6);
    for (Student s: ls) {
      s.print();
    }
    System.out.println("=====================");
    ls.sort(new Comparator < Student > () {
      @Override
      public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        if (s1.grade < s2.grade) return -1;
        // else if (s1.grade > s2.grade) return 1;
        else return 0;
      }
    });
    for (Student s: ls) {
      s.print();
    }
  }
  public static void printLs(List < Student > ls) {
    for (Student s: ls) {
      s.print();
    }
  }
}
class Student {
  String name;
  int grade;

  Student(String name, int grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  void print() {
    System.out.println(this.name + " - " + this.grade);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"If it is -1, then the two values will be [swapped]"* **Not necessarily.** E.g. the [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm doesn't use swapping at all. Don't make any assumptions about the algorithm used. It may be changed without notice.

Comment: *"The return value will be -1, 0 or 1 as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."* **Not necessarily.** Some implementations of `compare`/`compareTo` might do that, but some may return `<0`, `=0`, or `>0`, as they are allowed to do according to the specification, e.g. they are not restricted to return `-1` but can return e.g. `-42`. The exactly value can be anything and has no meaning.

Comment: *"Why do we need the return value 1?"* Because the **requirements** state that "the implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`". So if `x.compareTo(y)` returns -1, then `y.compareTo(x)` **must** return +1.

Answer (score 6):

> If it is -1, then the two values will be [swapped]

Not necessarily. It depends on what two elements the sorting code is calling your callback with. It may be that returning `-1` wouldn't make it swap them but returning `1` would.

> I tested my program without return value 1 and it sort correctly.

You just got lucky with the specific data you were sorting, which happened with the specific algorithm being used by the sorting code to not need your callback to be accurate. With other data, it wouldn't work correctly, because with the `else if` commented out, you'll return `0` (these two are the same) when they *aren't* the same because `s1` will be after `s2`.

Don't try to second-guess what the documentation is telling you, or how the specific implementation of `sort` works. Correctly implement the callback so it returns a negative number, zero, or a positive number depending on how to two elements you're given should be ordered.

Comment: What do you mean "It depends on what two elements the sorting code is calling your callback with"?

Comment: @NyeinChan - All you know is that it called your callback with `a` and `b`. You don't know what order `a` and `b` were in in the collection being sorted. `a` (or `b`) might be in the process of being relocated based on a previous comparison, for instance. All you know is that your callback has been asked to tell the sort algorithm what order those two elements should be in. Your sort callback's job is to accurately provide that information.

Answer (score -1):

I've modified your code to generate more data at the start to demonstrate that your dataset is too small to show the problem.

You can see and run it on [Coding Ground](http://tpcg.io/NzcrddhL). (I'm not affiliated)

Don't rely on an abstracted sort call to always use the same sort implementation. It can call different strategies depending on how big your data set is.